# why Tensorflow transpose failed in a certain scenario?

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
tf.reset_default_graph()

sess=tf.Session()

X=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[3,8])

X_1 = tf.reshape(X,[3,2,4])

print(X_1)

X_tensor = tf.transpose(X_1,[1,2,0])

print(X_tensor)
```

output:

```
Tensor("Reshape:0", shape=(3, 2, 4), dtype=float32)

Tensor("transpose:0", shape=(2, 4, 3), dtype=float32)
```

The transpose result should be `(4,3,2)`.

Answer (score 0):

You pass `perm=[1,2,0]` to `tf.transpose`, that's why you get `(2, 4, 3)` as shape from `(3, 2, 4)`. (see: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/transpose)

Try `X_tensor = tf.transpose(X_1,[2,0,1])` to get your desired result.